# jQuery insertAfter a button that is inside div with class

Tags: jquery

I have the following div:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" style="display:none;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    </div>
```

I need to append text and remove it later just after `</button>` tag.

My code is:

```
$('This is a test').insertAfter('.alert alert-danger > button');
```

So the expected out should be:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" style="display:none;">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
This is a Test
                        </div>
```

But is not working.

And I guess for removing will be something like:

```
$('.alert alert-danger > button').nextAll().remove();
```

> Any clue?

Comment: You want to insert it after button tag?can you be more clear on this

Comment: $('This is a test') it looks for a tag this is a test...which is wrong

Comment: jQuery insertAfter documentation, I copy a sample from there: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: Put the text in an element so `nextAll()` will find it. There are no direct jQuery methods for removing text nodes although it can be done but is much simpler removing elements

Comment: In jQuery docs api $("p") this is it looking for p tag...but here it is invalid html element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the text in an element and insert that. It will be far easier to remove than parsing through text nodes for which jQuery has no direct methods to access them

```
$('<span>').text('This is a test').insertAfter('.alert.alert-danger > button');
```

Now the nextAll().remove() should also work

Note that `$('some text')` is not valid for `$()`

Comment: That's not possible when used correctly. Create a demo that reproduces it

Comment: Works just fine here https://jsfiddle.net/aabnhx1L/ Note that you have `display:none` in the html currently

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong here. your code has $("This is a test") which is looking for a tag which is **this is a test** its wrong

I have just simulated your insertion of a text element and removal
in my code onload it inserts a div tag with some text on it and onclick of remove button it removes it

check the following snippet

```js
$(function(){
  var div=$("<div></div>");
  div.html("This is test div");
  
  div.insertAfter( $( ".alert button" ));
  
  $("#remove").click(function(){
   $(".alert").find('button').nextAll().remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" >
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
</div>

<input type=button id="remove" value=remove>
```

Hope it helps